# VB.NET FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: vb.net

What am I doing wrong here? I can't get a list of what files are in the folder I selected.

```
    If ListViewMain.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ListViewMain.Items.Clear()
    End If

    If FolderBrowserDialogMain.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fiFileInfo As New FileInfo(FolderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath)
        If fiFileInfo.Extension = ".mp3" Then
            Dim lviListViewItem As New ListViewItem
            lviListViewItem.Text = fiFileInfo.Name
            ListViewMain.Items.Add(lviListViewItem)
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.-ctor) with a directory path. You have to use [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.-ctor) instead. By using [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) you can get all files of the directory with a specific extension:

```
If ListViewMain.Items.Count > 0 Then
    ListViewMain.Items.Clear()
End If

If FolderBrowserDialogMain.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath)

    For Each fiInfo As FileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles("*.mp3")
        Dim lviListViewItem As New ListViewItem
        lviListViewItem.Text = fiInfo.Name
        ListViewMain.Items.Add(lviListViewItem)
    Next
End If
```